# How to add the datacursor to a bar chart with Matplotblib and PyQt5?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I try to add the datacursor functionality to my bar chart by using the following code:

```
datacursor(hover=True, formatter=self.formatter)
```

No error happens but tooltip doesn't show when I hover my mouse pointer over a bar.

I try to put the following code (and this one works perfectly) into a `QWidget`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

label = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, align='center', color='lightblue')
ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)

def formatter(**kwargs):
    dist = abs(np.array(x) - kwargs['x'])
    i = dist.argmin()
    return '\n'.join(label[i])

datacursor(hover=True, formatter=formatter)
plt.show()
```

Here my current code.

back_end:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget
from front_end import Ui_MainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.graph = MyCanvas()      
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        self.graph.figure.clf()
        self.axes= self.graph.figure.add_subplot(111)       
        label = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        y = [10, 20, 30, 40]
        datacursor(hover=True, formatter=self.formatter)
        self.axes.bar(x, y, align='center', bottom=0, color='b')

    def formatter(**kwargs):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        dist = abs(np.array(x) - kwargs['x'])
        i = dist.argmin()
        return '\n'.join(label[i])

class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        self.figure.patch.set_facecolor("None")
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, bottom=0.10, right=0.99, top=0.97)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = Ui_MainWindow()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

front_end:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(625, 460)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 625, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When asking about undesired behaviour always provide a [mcve]. I tried to make your code runnable but needed to give up half-way... just make sure someone can copy it from the question without needing to guess about missing things.

Comment: So to be more precise: What is `x` inside the `formatter` method? It's nowhere defined.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the code for the front_end. Hope it will help. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, but without `x` being defined the code can't run.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest a question, even if FigureCanvasQTAgg is used, will the native matplotlib events continue to be handled?

Comment: @eyllanesc Some are, some are not; it'll also depend on the focus policy which is set or not set. So it could well be that the focus needs to be set here, but one would need to test. Currently, it simply looks like because `x` is undefined, the callback fails.

Comment: I added a new piece of code for illustration of what I try to achieve. In that particular example, `x` is not defined inside the `formatter` method.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
I'm not the asker, try to see what the problem is by it eliminates all the formatter code and only returns "Hello World" and that callback is not called, checking the source code of datacursor I saw that it is handling native events of matplotlib, That's why it was my previous question.

Comment: Yeah, so the solution is to define `x`.

Comment: I defined `x` which `x = [1, 2, 3, 4]` but I have the same problem.

Comment: At least I can now run the code, knowing that `x` and `label` should be the same as used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

- `x` and `label` that are used inside of the `formatter` method need to be defined. A good solution would be to make them class variables.
- The `formatter` method should be a method of the class. Hence it would best be defined as one by using the `self` argument.
- Naming the class in use the same as an imported class may lead to confusion, best name it differently.
- The `datacursor` needs to know which objects to work on, hence one would need to first define the bar plot and later call the `datacursor` function with those bars as argument.
- There is no need to join anything on the return of the formatter, just return the label to show.

This should then look like

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    # ....

    def populate(self):
        self.graph.figure.clf()
        self.axes= self.graph.figure.add_subplot(111)       
        self.label = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        self.x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        self.y = [10, 20, 30, 40]
        bars = self.axes.bar(self.x, self.y, align='center', bottom=0, color='b')
        datacursor(bars, hover=True, formatter=self.formatter)

    def formatter(self, **kwargs):
        dist = abs(np.array(self.x) - kwargs['x'])
        i = dist.argmin()
        return self.label[i]
```